# SVN Merge to trunk, without marking all files as dirty

Tags: svn, merge

So i've followed the svnbook on merging, and the result is that all the files OTHER people have updated to the trunk, are marked as if I committed them again without a change.

is there a way of reintegrating the branch back to the trunk and that files which were unmodified won't be marked as they were committed again?

(does Git has this feature?)

thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your trunk working copy is not up to date.

Comment: i've done the following - created a branch, did my work, merged the trunk to the branch, committed all changes (it shows the updates from the trunk as changes - why?)
then merged my branch back to the trunk, and it added my commits  in the branch to the local folder of the trunk (including those files which were updated because i had to commit them to the branch), and then commit my trunk.

the result is that files which i didn't touch, but were added from the trunk to my branch, are now marked as if i committed them.